# Search for substring in string

Tags: python, string

I'm having a problem of writing a function `find_substr` that takes two arguments as input: a `substring` and a `string`. And searches for substring and returns a `tuple` representing the (start, stop) of the substring.

For example

```
find_substr("plan", "I plan to join summer camp")
Output:
(2, 6) 

find_substr("su", "summer vacation")
Output:
(0, 2)
```

Which string methods I have to use to search for string and convert it to tuple?

Answer (score 0):

you can use find method and do it like this:

```py
String= "mohammed farhan mohammed almalki"

SupString = "farhan"

def FindMySupString(SupString,String):
    return (String.find(SupString),String.find(SupString)+len(SupString)-1)
```

Output will be like this:

> (9, 14)

Comment: In Python you shouldn't use camel case for variables and function names. See [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).

Comment: Okay . Thank you very much.  I didn't know that.   But what is the benefit of that ? Will it make my code faster or only for readability?

Comment: It doesn't make the code faster. [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) is a set of (non-binding) format conventions the Python creators/maintainers agreed upon. It makes reading Python code easier, which is important (see e.g. [here](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/#why-we-need-pep-8) for a short explanation).

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_substr(substring:str, string:str) -> tuple:
    start = string.find(substring)
    stop = start + len(substring)
    return (start, stop)

find_substr("plan", "I plan to join summer camp")
```

(2, 6)